# ASP.NET Core 7.0 Web API : SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

There is a `database.db` file that I created with SQLite in my Web API application that I developed with .NET 7.0. I am accessing the `database.db` file located in `C:\\Windows\\System32` with the Web API launched as a service and performing reading and writing operations.

However, when I run it with debug via VS 2022, when I want to get or post, I get a SQLite

> Error 14: unable to open database file

There is no problem when running as a service, but if I start it as debug, it cannot open the database file.

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions on the file to access it?

Comment: Even for a Service, that might not be the best place to put that file. Maybe consider `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` ?

Comment: @DavidG yes, I gave everyone full control of the file.

Comment: @Fildor i will try

Comment: @MMK that's a *very* bad idea. So bad that Windows may *prevent* access to that file from non-administrator applications. Store the file in a normal folder instead

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Do you mean the system32 folder or CommonApplicationData is a bad idea? I am guessing System32...

Comment: System32. In fact, if the API runs under IIS, the app pool account won't have any permissions to that folder

Comment: Did you run VisualStudio using Administrator account?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.

I gave full permission to Everyone to authorize the Database.db file.

Comment: Maybe also consider _not_ placing it in the system folder.

Comment: If this did not solve your problem but is additional info, then please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77236523/edit) your question instead of posting an answer to it.